# Is there a minimal message queue?

Tags: java, linux, http, message-queue, messaging

I'm searching for a minimal message queue project.

With minimal I mean something along this:

- No/Minimal setup / administration
- Uses http (so I don't need protocol/queue specific libraries/code)
- (Persistence would get extra points ;)
- (It should run on linux.)

Is there such a project available? I once heard about a message queue utilizing HTTP as the procotocol layer, but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 2):

[httpsqs](http://code.google.com/p/httpsqs/) (HTTP Simple Queue Service, message queue based on HTTP GET/POST protocol) is probably the tool you're looking for.

I haven't had the chance to try it, but its feature set seems to meet your requirements.